# Does this lead to a contradiction within ZF?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

Let the following be an axiom (which I will denote P):

> If $x,y$ are sets and $f:y\to x$ is a surjection, then the existence of an injection $f:x\to y$ guarantees a choice function exists.

Does P lead to contradiction within ZF in any obvious Russell's paradox like sense?

Comment: How about a set theory with just two axioms, extensionality and "all sets exist"?

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to AC?

Comment: What exactly does "every injection from $y$ into $x$" mean?

Comment: How exactly do you *phrase* $P$? ["Definable" isn't actually definable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem), and "every [thing with property $A$] exists" is just $\forall x(A(x)\rightarrow \exists y(x=y))$ which is trivially true (first-order logic doesn't have the ability to talk about contingently-existing objects).

Comment: How do you express "exists" and "is definable" in the language of set theory?

Comment: Also, your argument that $P$ implies AC starts by assuming AC.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah. I see your point about definability being undefinable in first-order logic. I think that would require quantification over sets. But to the second point. Does the axiom of choice not imply the existence of a function (namely a choice function)? Why is it required if we can assert the existence of any function via extensionality?

Comment: It sounds like what you mean to say is something like: "if $f:x\to y$ is a surjection and there exists an injection $y\to x$, then $f$ has a choice function".  This is different from what you said, since your condition "a surjection implies the existence of an injection" is true vacuously if no surjection exists".

Comment: @EricWofsey yes. That's much better. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to say that if there is a surjection from $y$ onto $x$, then if there is any injection, there is one splitting the surjection.

This cannot *lead* to contradiction, since it follows from the Axiom of Choice. Another question would be whether or not this implies the Axiom of Choice. This is a bit more complicated.

Let "The Partition Principle" denote the statement "if there is a surjection from $y$ to $x$, then there is an injection". And what we're asking is: Does the Partition Principle implies AC provable from $\sf ZF$? And the answer is that we don't know.